# Golang/mgo : How can I store ISODate by GMT+8 Time Zone in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go

If I store ISODate in mongodb,the ISODate is always GMT+0

```
type StoreTime struct {
    storeTime time.Time `bson:"testTime" json:"testTime,omitempty"`
}
...
t := StoreTime {
    storeTime : time.Now(),
}
....
c.Insert(t)
```

The result is :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("578b43e5feaa0deb6a94b1d0"),  
    "storeTime" : ISODate("2016-07-17T08:38:25.316+0000")
}
```

How can I change the time zone?

Answer (score 4):

<strike>You came across an intricacy of mgo.v2/bson, which converts</strike> Since the [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) states that all times shall be stored as

> UTC milliseconds since the Unix epoch

`mgo.v2/bson` converts all time.Time values to UTC. So even when you explicitly set the location info of a time returned by `time.Now()` or companions, this local time is converted to UTC.

So in order to display time correctly for any given time zone, you should do the following:

1. When saving a time.Time value, you should use the time as returned by `time.Time.In(*time.Location)` if the time zone differs from your (the servers) local time.
2. When displaying the returned value in UTC, make sure you use `time.Time.UTC()`
3. When displaying the returned value in a given local time, make sure you use `time.Time.In(*time.Location)` again.

To be a more clear on that, please have a look at the example below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

const (
    myLoc = "Europe/Berlin"
    ny    = "America/New_York"
)

// We define those vars here, as you might want to make them
// package-global
var (
    berlin *time.Location
    nyc    *time.Location
)

// StoreTime is just a dummy struct
type StoreTime struct {
    // Unexported fields are not (un-)marshalled by encoding/json
    // and mgo.v2/bson, so the field name has to be uppercase
    StoreTime time.Time `bson:"testTime"`
}

func main() {

    var (
        sess *mgo.Session
        err  error
    )

    // Connect to MongoDB
    if sess, err = mgo.Dial("localhost:27017"); err != nil {
        panic("Could not connect to MongoDB: " + err.Error())
    }
    // Make sure the session is closed when main exits for whatever reason
    defer sess.Close()

    // Clear the collection for demo purposes
    if err = sess.DB("test").C("timezones").Remove(bson.M{}); err != nil && err != mgo.ErrNotFound {
        panic("Could not clean test collection: " + err.Error())
    }

    // Load the desired TZ by location
    if berlin, err = time.LoadLocation(myLoc); err != nil {
        panic("Error loading '" + myLoc + "' as timezone location: " + err.Error())
    }

    // Create a new StoreTime with the local time of the desired timezone.
    // Note that mgo.v2/bson still converts it to Zulu time, but with the
    // appropriate offset.
    st := &StoreTime{StoreTime: time.Now().In(berlin)}

    // Save the document for further reference
    if err = sess.DB("test").C("timezones").Insert(st); err != nil {
        panic("Error inserting sample document into MongoDB: " + err.Error())
    }

    // Load the saved document,...
    res := &StoreTime{}
    if err = sess.DB("test").C("timezones").Find(nil).One(&res); err != nil {
        panic("Unable to load just recently stored document: " + err.Error())
    }

    // ... and another TZ for displaying,...
    if nyc, err = time.LoadLocation(ny); err != nil {
        panic("Error loading '" + ny + "' as timezone location: " + err.Error())
    }

    // ...and display the time from the document in UTC and the local time
    // of both Berlin and NYC.
    fmt.Println(res.StoreTime.UTC())
    // The next two are identical for _me_, as I happen to live in the according TZ.
    // Unless you do, too, you should have different values
    fmt.Println(res.StoreTime.In(Berlin))
    fmt.Println(res.StoreTime)
    fmt.Println(res.StoreTime.In(nyc))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`time.Now` should return local time. Is your system time setup properly? What do you get on running the `date` command (on linux based system)?

You can try using `In` method on you `time` object with a `time.Location` value:

```
l, _ := time.LoadLocation("Local") // or the name of your time zone
t : time.Now()

t := StoreTime {
    storeTime : t.In(l),
}
```

Comment: For clarification, please use comments.